# Image Gallery: Mouse Move within div container

Tags: jquery, image, gallery, mousemove

I have managed to create a sequence of inline images within a `div` container. The images move left to right (inverted) depending on the mouse position within the `div` container.

The problem I face now is that the left and right movement of the images are far too stilted and need to be more fluid.

Perhaps I need to implement the `.animate()` function, but I am not sure?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the Fiddle of the working Image Gallery -http://jsfiddle.net/q4wcL5yb/22/

And here is the idea I have, yet am unsure of how to implement it into my Image Gallery - http://jsfiddle.net/fhmkf/

JS

```
(function ($) {

 var $scrollContent = $(".img-wrap");

    $(window).mousemove(function(e){
       var windowWidth = $(window).width();
       var contentWidth = $scrollContent.width();

    // Calculate the x offset as a percentage of the window width
    var mouseOffsetPercent = e.pageX / windowWidth;

    var amountToMoveContent = ( windowWidth - contentWidth ) * mouseOffsetPercent;

    console.log( amountToMoveContent, mouseOffsetPercent );


    $scrollContent.css({
      'transform': 'translateX(' + amountToMoveContent + 'px)'
    });

  });

})(jQuery)
```

Thanks.